# R use string to refer to column

Tags: r, string, subset

I would like to subset a dataframe by referring to a column with a string and select the values of that column that fulfill a condition.
From the following code

```
 employee <- c('John Doe','Peter Gynn','Jolie Hope')
 salary <- c(21000, 23400, 26800)
 startdate <- as.Date(c('2010-11-1','2008-3-25','2007-3-14'))
 employ.data <- data.frame(employee, salary, startdate)
 salary_string <- "salary"
```

I want to get all salaries over 23000 by using the **salary_string** to refer to the column name.

I tried without succes:

```
set <- subset(employ.data, salary_string > 23000)
set2 <- employ.data[, employ.data$salary_string > 23000)
```

This does not seem to work because the salary_string is of type character but what I need is some sort of "column name object". Using as.name(salary_string) does not work neither.
I know I could get the subset by using

```
set <- subset(employ.data, salary > 23000)
```

But my goal is to use the column name that is of type character (salary_string) once with subset(employ.data, ... ) and once with employ.data[, ...]

Comment: Care to explain the rationale behind what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: I'm creating a function that takes a string/character as input and if the input matches the column name, the function should create a subset of the values of the column that fulfill a condition

Comment: An ugly alternative: `subset(employ.data,eval(parse(text=salary_string)) > 23000)`

Comment: @Frank Almost the same comment at the same time ;)

Comment: @Simon, got it. It made me practice writing functions using dplyr. Let me know if need any hints for tht

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Short answer is: do not use `subset` but
something like

```
employ.data[employ.data[salary_string]>23000,]
```

Comment: even shorter `employ.data[employ.data["salary"]>23000,]`

Comment: Yes, but I think he wants to use the variable and not the string directly, if I am not mistaken.

Comment: BTW: Here is the post that explains why it's better to use `[` instead of `subset`. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9860090/in-r-why-is-better-than-subset

Answer (score 3):

Here's another idea:

```
dplyr::filter(employ.data, get(salary_string) > 23000)
```

Which gives:

```
#    employee salary  startdate
#1 Peter Gynn  23400 2008-03-25
#2 Jolie Hope  26800 2007-03-14
```

Answer (score 2):

For the sake of showing how to achieve the result with `subset()`:

The issue you're having is because `subset()` uses non-standard evaluation.  Here's one way to substitute your string into the `subset()` function.

```
## set up an unevaluated call
e <- call(">", as.name(salary_string), 23000)
## evaluate it in subset()
subset(employ.data, eval(e))
#     employee salary  startdate
# 2 Peter Gynn  23400 2008-03-25
# 3 Jolie Hope  26800 2007-03-14
```

Or as Steven suggests, the following would also work well.

```
subset(employ.data, eval(as.name(salary_string)) > 23000)
```

Comment: Another hacky way that I strongly discourage to use ;) `subset(employ.data,eval(parse(text=paste0(salary_string,">","23000"))))`

Comment: Why not `subset(employ.data, eval(as.name(salary_string)) > 23000)` ?

Comment: Yeah that too @StevenBeaupré!  I'm a little rusty. Been off the grid for a while :)

Comment: Again, I think the examples with `subset` and `eval` are kind of nice if you want to play around with the parsing, but should not be used in production code. You can get in all kinds of trouble. Who knows what R is really doing behind the scenes when it evaluates the `subset` argument? At least I don't.